# I have the SAS url that contains list of files ,the container name and the file path of each file and I want to download them using python

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

container name: task
file path example: -task/input/data.csv
-task/input/cost.txt

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

sasUrl = "sas url here"

blobNameWithContainer = "file path"

sasUrlParts = urlparse(sasUrl)

accountEndpoint = sasUrlParts.scheme + '://' + sasUrlParts.netloc

sasToken = sasUrlParts.query

blobSasUrl = accountEndpoint + '/' + blobNameWithContainer + '?' + sasToken

blobClient = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blobSasUrl)
```

Comment: What's the issue you are running with this code?

Comment: The code finishes excuting without doing anything

Comment: Where in your code are you downloading the blob? All you’re doing is creating an instance of blob client. You would need to add the code to download the blob.

Comment: can you provide me with this code?

Comment: Please search for it. You’ll find ample code samples to download blob using Python SDK.

Comment: all samples found required creating an account on azure and the requirements specified not to do so